# Rspec generate "it do" from array

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

How generate it test from array

```
describe "some test" do
  let(:some) { generated_array }

  # raise error - undefined local variable or method
  some.each do |key|
    it "#{key} test" do
      true
    end
  end

  # will work
  [1,2,3].each do |key|
   ...

end
```

How it can be realyzed with RSpec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have your test using the `let` in the outer context that way due to RSpec being a DSL. RSpec reads the example spec files first, before running the tests. It hits the `some.each` during DSL parsing before any of the actual tests are run.

This errors because `some` gets defined on the example object, but the `describe` and `context` run in the an example group object context.

You can see this with:

```
describe 'thing' do
  p self.ancestors
  #=> [#<Class:0x007fa97a0761f8>, RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup, RSpec::Matchers,
  #    RSpec::Core::MockFrameworkAdapter, RSpec::Core::SharedExampleGroup,
  #    RSpec::Core::Pending, RSpec::Core::Extensions::InstanceEvalWithArgs,
  #    RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::LetDefinitions,
  #    RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::NamedSubjectPreventSuper,
  #    RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel,
  #    BasicObject]

  it { p selfs }
  #=> #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007f8d1b397790 ...>
end
```